# FFmpeg Live streaming Error: ffmpeg av_interleaved_write_frame broken pipe. Conversion Failed

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, ubuntu-server, ffserver

I am trying to stream video live using ffmpeg. videos stream is coming from a camera over the network and there is bunch error that i got in initial part of doing this but here i am stacked with a error that is coming from ffmpeg where it says av_interleaved_write_frame() broken pipe,then at the end i get a message saying conversion failed ,when i want to capture the stream in any format it works like a charm but when it comes to streaming it gives the error.Why this is happening?

the command i am using to get the streaming is here:

```
ffmpeg - i rtsp://10.63.191.250/aerostat http://10.20.1.142:8080/feed.ffm
or 
ffmpeg - i rtsp://10.63.191.250/aerostat -acodec copy -vcodec copy http://10.20.1.142:8080/feed.ffm
//with both the command i am getting the same error
```

The ffmpeg out put is Here:

```
[h264 @ 0x3965b40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3965b40] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3965b40] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x3965b40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x3965b40] no frame!
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.63.191.250/aerostat':
Metadata:
title : \Aerostat
Duration: N/A, start: 63184.792467, bitrate: N/A
Program 1
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 77 kb/s
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B),     yuv420p(progressive), 656x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 41:23], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k  tbn, 59.94 tbc
[libvpx @ 0x397a360] v1.6.0
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://10.20.1.142:8080/feed.ffm':
Metadata:
title : \Aerostat
creation_time : now
encoder : Lavf57.56.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc57.64.101 libvorbis
Stream #0:1: Video: vp8 (libvpx), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 164:115 DAR   41:23], q=10-42, 400 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1000k tbn, 25 tbc
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc57.64.101 libvpx
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 800000 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (h264 (native) -> vp8 (libvpx))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
Last message repeated 6 times
Error writing trailer of http://10.20.1.142:8080/feed.ffm: Broken pipeframe= 6 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize= 52kB time=00:00:00.43 bitrate=  972.0kbits/s dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.778x
video:43kB audio:3kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB  muxing overhead: 13.661202%
Conversion failed!
```

Here is My FFserver.conf file:

```
HTTPPort 8080 # Port to bind the server to
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000 # Maximum bandwidth per client
# set this high enough to exceed stream bitrate
CustomLog -
<Feed feed.ffm> # This is the input feed where FFmpeg will send
File ./feed.ffm # video stream.
FileMaxSize 1G # Maximum file size for buffering video
ACL allow 10.20.0.0 10.20.255.255 # Allowed IPs
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost
</Feed>
<Stream live.webm> # Output stream URL definition
Feed feed.ffm # Feed from which to receive video
Format webm
# Audio settings
AudioCodec vorbis
Audi0oBitRate 64 # Audio bitrate
# Video settings
VideoCodec libvpx
VideoSize 720x576 # Video resolution
VideoFrameRate 25 # Video FPS
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header # Parameters passed to encoder
# (same as ffmpeg command-line parameters)
AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
AVOptionVideo qmin 10
AVOptionVideo qmax 42
AVOptionVideo quality good
AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
PreRoll 15
StartSendOnKey
VideoBitRate 400 # Video bitrate
</Stream>
<Stream status.html> # Server status URL
Format status
# Only allow local people to get the status
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow 10.20.0.0 10.20.255.255
</Stream>
<Redirect index.html> # Just an URL redirect for index
# Redirect index.html to the appropriate site
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

Comment: I also encountered the same issue....

Comment: @iownthegame comment all AVOption parts in config file thats  what solved my problem the reason idk at all why ,but you can check on every parameter that you pass in config file.

Comment: @A Sahra but the thing is I'm not using my own ffmpeg server, I use Wowza Stream Cloud. Is there any thing I can do for the ffmpeg client?

Comment: I got the same error. Do you have any solutions?